# Is there a way to calculate how a point source would be imaged in a system with spherical aberration?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I want to create a picture like this for the system I am building.

[image]
(Source: [WP page on spherical aberration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_aberration))

Can someone point me towards a book were I can learn to calculate this pattern on an imagining plane. Is ray tracing the wrong way to go about creating a picture like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Virendra Mahajan's *Optical Imaging and Aberrations, part II*. It describes everything that happens from the lens to the focal plane area in terms of EM wave. Geometrical optics alone cannot be used to create this picture.

If you want less math and something more practical, the softwares *Zemax, CodeV or Oslo* are great tools to get such figures. You just enter your design specs and it does the rest for you. It has a lot more features and is mainly used to design and optimize optical systems.

Finally, and this might be your best  solution, i am pretty sure there are some Matlab scripts that people wrote and shared on *MatlabCentral* file exchange.

Comment: Thank you! My Prof. wants me to learn about this, so to the books I go!